# Track fatal errors in PHP using register_shutdown_function for "Errors on line 0"

Tags: php, error-handling, fatal-error

I am using register_shutdown_function to track fatal errors:

```
function fatalErrorShutdownHandler()
{

  $last_error = error_get_last();

  if ($last_error['type'] === E_ERROR) { 
    // fatal error
    mail('..., 'fatal error '.time(), $last_error['type'].' '.$last_error['message'].' '.$last_error['file'].' '.$last_error['line']);

  }
}

register_shutdown_function('fatalErrorShutdownHandler');
```

Everything works as expected, I receive an email when a fatal error occurs.

I have a script that uses a large amount of memory (huge associative arrays, `explode` of big pieces of text, `array_combine` ... ) that, staying with the default memory limit set by my hosting provider (128M) produces this error:

*Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3438 bytes) in Unknown on line 0*

My first question is: why sometime PHP isn't able to say exactly the line where the error occurred?

I have temporary solved the problem increasing the memory limit, but what I really want to understand is how can I track this kind of errors? When I receive a "in line 0" error the `fatalErrorShutdownHandler()` function doesn't work as expected, it is executed but error_get_last() returns NULL so I can't track the error.

Comment: the error its hard to say, likely it happens in the first file that is loaded and them PHP never knows what that file is because it never finishes.  All that said is beside the point, because that is the result of the problem and not the actual problem.  If you know you are doing memory intensive stuff, perhaps you can refactor you code to reduce the memory consumption at any given point in time.  If you can describe what you are doing in more detail, such as reading CSV files there may be ways to do a line, dump it and thereby clear that memory for reuse.

Comment: I can improve the code for sure, but the point is that, anyway, it could happen again, I cannot be 100% sure about.... and there is no way to track it?
I can't understand why sometime memory errors provide the exact line, e.g. it refers to a variable assignment statement (and therefore error_get_last works as expected) and sometime not. What is the reason why PHP loses controls of that?

Comment: I believe this happens "Unknown" if the error occurs in the file that registers the shutdown handler, so if that is the case you'll what a simpler file to include the other and register the shutdown before including that one ( the main one ).

Comment: I've tried to avoid the use of register_shutdown_function but still I got "Unknown on line 0" so it seems the problem is not in the shutdown handler.

Comment: That was not what I said, is the script all one big file, does the error occur in the first file ran?

Comment: sorry I probably misunderstood your sentence but it's not clear to me what you mean. Yes, the same file contains the main code and the register_shutdown_function, the only file included is the ADODB library. As I said, I've also tried to comment the register_shutdown_function sentence.